# Aligning an image with the text in a text view

Tags: android

I want to display a small image somewhere between my text. So, I used a text view and using `Spannable` assigned the image/drawable at the appropriate position. The following is the code.

```
 ImageSpan is=new ImageSpan(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.up);
Spannable sb=new SpannableString(text);
sb.setSpan(is, start,end,0);
textView.setText(sb);
```

The image comes up in the right position but the problem is that the image is nor aligned with the text properly. The image is display below the text.

Is there a way to align the image with the text?

Comment: you want image between text or in left/right?

Comment: Please add what you got as result

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
ImageSpan is=new ImageSpan(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.up, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
```

This will align the bottom of the above span with the baseline of the surrounding text, as mentioned in the [ImageSpan documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan.html).